# Exporting Windows 7 Group Policy into Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, group-policy

I have multiple computers in Windows 7 that have same configuration and settings with the same hardware. I want to migrate Windows 7 to Windows 10. Is there any proper way to export Group Policy Settings from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: I assume these machines are not connected to an active directory domain?

Comment: Yes, it`s not connected to any active directory domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft makes a command-line tool for this as part of the [Security Compoliance Toolkit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-compliance-toolkit-10).  The Security Compliance Toolkit is mostly documentation and Group Policy templates containing baseline security settings for various versions of Windows, so it might be worth a look if you're interested in that sort of thing.  But the component you're looking for is the Local Group Policy Object (LGPO) tool (you can download just that component from the link I provided).

To back up the local GPO on Windows 7, you would run `lgpo.exe /b "C:\foo"`.
To restore the GPO to Windows 10, you would run: `lgpo.exe /g "C:\foo"`.

I have not tested this tool myself, so I don't know how well it works, but I have used the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit and SCCM to import GPO templates into OS images before and that works well.

One thing I should note here:
If you're just *upgrading* Win7 to Win10 on the same machine, you don't need to bother with backing up/restoring the local GPO.  The settings you've got will carry over to the Win10 install.  You only need to do this if you're doing a fresh install of Win10 on new hardware.

Comment: I will try lgpo.exe   Does Windows 7 gpo have the same structure as Windows 10? Because from what I read abot lgpo.exe tool it just backup the gpo into some type of file and restore it back to another computer. Most of only from 1 computer to another computer with same os.